# Refresh causes app to break

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular App which loads fine for the first time, but as soon as I refresh it or press F5 it breaks and gives the following error:

**core.es5.js:350 Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators**

If reflect-metadata shim is required and I haven't included it, why is it starting properly on the first upload?

Comment: Has the URL in the browser changed when the page is refreshed?

Comment: Nope, it hasn't. It's the same.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your problem
As I am using [angular cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) I have a file [polyfils.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/blueprints/ng/files/__path__/polyfills.ts) having this lines of code:

```
/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

So I commented that and my app just didn't load at first, throwing an error `Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators`. I tried IE11, latest Chrome and FF - all behaving same giving `Uncaught reflect-metadata shim` error on first load.

Why error is not getting throwed at first in your case I am not sure, may be you are running some specific browser, etc. But you definitely need `reflect` polyfill to be included in order to run angular app even in the latest browsers.